# Am I using angular (2) modules correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module

I am developing the following demo app:

A user is shown a list of countries (all displayed as a card with basic info and image). When a country is clicked they are routed into the detail of that country in which I also show a list of attractions for the country (e.g. the Eiffel tower and Louvre museum for France).

Countries:

[image]

Country detail with list of attractions:

[image]

This is my project structure

```
/app
  /attractions
    /attraction (COMPONENT)
    /attraction-list (COMPONENT)
    attraction (CLASS)
    attraction.service
    attractions.routing
    attractions.module (EXPORTS 'AttractionListComponent')
  /countries
    /country (COMPONENT)
    /country-detail (COMPONENT, Uses '<attraction-list></attraction-list>')
    /country-list (COMPONENT)
    country (CLASS)
    country.service
    countries.module (IMPORTS AttractionsModule)
    countries.routing
  app.module (IMPORTS CountriesModule)
  app.routing
```

Everything works but I do have some questions:

- Is my architecture following good practices? If not, what should I change?
- Are my module imports correct, e.g. should I import AttractionsModule in the root AppModule (When I did this it complained because CountryDetail couldn't recognise `<attraction-list></attraction-list>`
- What will happend when I incorporate lazy loading, how will it affect my setup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to post this on the stackExchange [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which specialize in reviewing working code.

Comment: Thanks! Will do :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz The thing is that adding code is not really that helpful for the questions I have, I suppose.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Any other place I can post this to?